# Short-term parking costs

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, british-english, phrasing

Could somebody please help me out with the following?

Is this ok:

"The average short-term parking costs are €2.10 per hour in the municipality".

Or should I write one of the following:

- "The average short-stay parking costs are €2.10 per hour in the municipality".
- "The average costs for short term/stay parking are €2.10 per hour in the municipality"

Thanks in advance!

A Dutch student

P.S. Looking for British-English advice

Comment: Both are used and idiomatic. Choose one though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native Brit, I would write: "The average price for short stay parking in the municipality is..."

I prefer price to cost because the latter potentially means the costs of providing the service not the amount people have to pay.

Short-term has other meanings too, so I preferred short stay which is specific to parking.

Comment: Yes, as a Brit, I agree.

Comment: As a native Brit I wouldn't use "municipality", I'd use "city".

Comment: Gosh! Really? One of the things that irritates me when asked for my address on websites is to state my city.  As it happens, I live in one, but most English towns, even very large ones, are not cities.

Comment: @JeremyC - Ok, I can see that that would get annoying. On an address form "Town/City" is fairly common. "Municipality" is a word I rarely encounter. And in this particular sentence the OP is talking about a specific one (hence the definite article), and hence could replace with either "town" or "city" as appropriate.